# How do I record using MediaRecorder to a file I have released using MediaPlayer in Android Studio using Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create an app where I loop a default sound when I press the play button, pause it when I press the pause button, and record to the sound file when I press the record button. The first 2 parts work, the last part breaks with these error messages:

```
kotlin
e: file:///Users/seanmcknelly/AndroidStudioProjects/CustomBabyShusher/app/src/main/java/com/example/custombabyshusher/MainActivity.kt:89:45 None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun setOutputFile(p0: File!): Unit defined in android.media.MediaRecorder
public open fun setOutputFile(p0: FileDescriptor!): Unit defined in android.media.MediaRecorder
public open fun setOutputFile(p0: String!): Unit defined in android.media.MediaRecorder
```

In the Android Studio IDE, it puts red underline on the setOutputFile method, and I am not sure why.

Here is the source code:

```
kotlin
package com.example.custombabyshusher

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.Companion.White
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.custombabyshusher.R.raw.shush1


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
           RunApp()
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun RunApp(){
    generateButtons(modifier = Modifier)
}

@Composable
fun generateButtons(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val mContext = LocalContext.current
    var mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, shush1)
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener{mp -> mp.start()}
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(1F, 1F)
    var recorder: MediaRecorder? = null
    var isRecording by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val imageResource = when (isRecording) {
        true -> R.drawable.notrecording
        else -> R.drawable.recording
    }
    Box (modifier){
        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.background(White)
        ) {
            IconButton(
                onClick = {
                    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying && !isRecording) {
                        mediaPlayer.start()
                    }
                },
                modifier = Modifier.size(250.dp)
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.play),
                    contentDescription = "Play"
                )
            }
            IconButton(onClick = { mediaPlayer.pause() },
                modifier = Modifier.size(250.dp)) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.pause),
                    contentDescription = "Pause"
                )
            }
            IconButton(onClick = {if (isRecording == false){
                                        mediaPlayer.stop()
                                        mediaPlayer.release()
                                        recorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
                                            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
                                            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
                                            setOutputFile(shush1)
                                            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
                                            prepare()
                                            start()
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if (isRecording == true && recorder != null) {
                                        recorder = MediaRecorder().apply{
                                            stop()
                                            reset()
                                            release()
                                        }
                                    }
                                    isRecording = !isRecording
                                 },
                modifier = Modifier.size(250.dp)){
                Image(painter = painterResource(imageResource),
                    contentDescription = "recording button")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.raw.shush1` is a resource identifier.

The `setOutputFile()` method of `MediaRecorder` doesn't accept resource identifiers. The reason for this is that resources are read-only at runtime. In other words you are not allowed to write to a resource file.

You must give `MediaRecorder` a writable file (e.g. a new file in a directory in which the app has a write permission, such as the one provided by `context.filesDir`).